# free and open source alternative to extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I noticed that ExtJS has changed drastically since last time I've checked it out. Right now it can only be used for free in an open source application - otherwise it requires a commercial license.

Is there something free/open source these days that's a viable alternative for extjs? My main goal is to have a javascript framework that can help me build together attractive UIs with minimal work. I'm not a designer, and ExtJS used to let me put together presentable UIs for mockups.